# How can i pass data from parent to child using props

Tags: reactjs

i have parent child component in reactJs i want to pass parent data to detail component using props.

I tried as shown below but i am not able to display the data in keeps redirect me to the parent component

Parent / Mater Page

```
render() {
    const cardKeys = Object.keys(cardData);
    return (
      <div className="scroll-list">
        {cardData.data.Table.map((results, index) => {
          return (
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="card ">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <div class="row">

                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                      <a href="mailto:{results.email_address}">{results.id}</a>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="row">                   
                    <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                      <a href="mailto:{results.email_address}">
                        {results.first_name}
                      </a>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Card details/child compoment

```
const Card = props => {
  const { id } = props.match.params;
  return (
    <div className="card-details">
      <h2>{cardData.data.Table[id].first_name}{cardData.data.Table[id].last_name}</h2>
      <h2>{cardData.data.Table[id].email_address}</h2>    
      <Link
        to={{
          pathname: "/cards",
          state: props.location.state
        }}
      >
        <button>Return to list</button>
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Main App router compoment
    function App() {
      return (
        
          
            
              
              
            
          
        
      );
    }

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the code like this.
    add the route path of home like

```
    <Route path="/" component={Cards} />
```

and in your child component

```
      var x = this.props.cardData;
      var id = 1001; //need to change/get from parent id value
      var index = 0; 
      for(var i = 0; i<x.data.Table.length; i++) {
         if(id === x.data.Table[i].id) { 
           index = i; 
         } 
      } 
      // const id = 0; 
      return ( <div className="card-details">
                 <h2> {cardData.data.Table[i].first_name} 
                 {cardData.data.Table[i].last_name} 
                 {cardData.data.Table[i].email_address} </h2>
```

your remaining code here

And another thing to change class="" to className="";

Hope this will fix your issue.

Comment: i get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined` in this line `>  99 |     var x = this.props.cardData;`

Comment: No i will make it answered but i want to get that part work 90% is done, Thank you

Comment: how can i import cardData you mean the .json file? im working https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-gates-2xkl7.. i created the detail page